# DataGridView show null decimal value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I'm programming an app in C# and I would like to show the data from the textboxes in the dgv. However, when I enter the value through the cart button, the value appears at 0 (as shown in the image below). can anybody help me?

[Running program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V73R.png)

Here's the code:

```
dgv_Carrinho.ColumnCount = 4;
            dgv_Carrinho.Columns[0].Name = "Produto";
            dgv_Carrinho.Columns[1].Name = "Valor";
            dgv_Carrinho.Columns[2].Name = "Quantidade";
            dgv_Carrinho.Columns[3].Name = "Hora";
            dgv_Carrinho.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dgv_Carrinho.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dgv_Carrinho.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            // Casa decimal DataGridView
            dgv_Carrinho.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
            // Introduçãol das textoxes na datagridview
            dgv_Carrinho.Rows.Add(txt_Produto.Text, subtotal, cmb_Quantidade.Text, txt_Hora.Text);
```

Ps.: Carrinho = cart (like supermarket cart); Gravar = save; Produtos = Products; Hora = Hour; Quantidade = Quantity;

Answer (score 0):

You add a row to you dgv_Carrinhh with the value of Subtotal.
But maybe nothing will update this in the DGV. You have to change the value each time you Subtotal change, with something like this

```
dgv_CArrinho.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = subtotal
```

But this is not a bit heavy to use. you can check the concept of datasource, to link a classe to you datagridview and dont have to manually set the value each time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8